# EntireRow.Delete is affecting my Conditional Formatting ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for away to delete rows without it affecting my conditional formatting ranges that I've applied to my worksheet. I want my CF ranges to stay the same (ex. $A$1:$A$5000) but whenever my code deletes a row, the second number (5000) is reduced by one, when I want it to stay the same. Is there anyway I can delete my rows **without** it affecting the CF?

I also know that I could just apply conditional formatting to the worksheet with a dynamic range each time I run the macro, but I'd rather not go through the hassle of rewriting ~20 CF scenarios into VBA for this macro if I can just avoid it changing all together. Here is my loop which steps through the rows and deletes them if it meets the criteria:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").Activate
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "R").Value) = "Business" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next I
```

I've thought that an alternative solution would be to add a simple loop to cycle through all my CFs that are set up and drag them down to the lastrow. Would this be a viable alternative?

Comment: You can use INDEX as your references in the all your CF: `$A$1:$A$5000` = `INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,5000)`

Comment: Maybe use this range instead to define your CF? `Range("A:A")` as that will apply to the entire column.

Comment: @braX Sorry my example above was poor, I can't use the whole column of A because there are a couple header rows which force me to start at A4, and it won't let me choose `$A$4:$A` as an option

Comment: You can set the entire column, and then after that remove the CF from the individual cells that dont need it.

Comment: @Scott Craner Scott I'm not sure where I should be trying to enter your solution, in the Formula Values where this formula is true field?

Comment: @braX Scratch my old comment, interestingly enough, if I set it to 1048576 and leave it at that, even deleting rows doesn't change it... very interesting...

Comment: So if your CF formula is `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5000,A1)>4` it would become `=COUNTIF(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,5000),A1)>4` and your applies to would be `=INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,5000)`  Now when rows are deleted it will remain on all 5000 rows.

Comment: @ScottCraner An example of one of my formulas is `=AND(N2<=TODAY()-14,OR($Q2="",$O2=""))`, so I never check against a range, I only check against the row itself. But the range to which I apply this formula might be `B2:B5000`

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah so I can still alter the applies to with index? Let me give that a shot. Edit: No luck, I don't add the applies to programmatically, I just put it in manually, and when I enter that in the applies to field it just instantly changes back to `$A$1:$A$5000`

Comment: Yup, appears to be something that many have complained about.  Hopefully in the future they will fix it.  Sorry.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for your help anyways. I ended up just setting them all to `$A$2:$A$1048576` and it stays like that just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quick loop should change the terminating row of every CFR on the worksheet to 5000 assuming that they start in row 1.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").Cells
    For cfr = 1 To .FormatConditions.Count
        With .FormatConditions(cfr)
            If .AppliesTo.Cells(.AppliesTo.Cells.Count).Row < 5000 Then
                .ModifyAppliesToRange Range:=.AppliesTo.Cells(1).Resize(5000)
            End If
        End With
    Next cfr
End With
```

Comment: Although not mentioned in the question, deleting or inserting rows can also lead to CFR's 'splitting', so to say, in multiple ranges. The code above does not prevent a large array of CFR's from being created due to rows being inserted or deleted.